# R - ggplot2 contour plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to replicate the code from Andrew Ng's Machine Learning course on Coursera in R (as the course is in Octave).

Basically I have to plot a non linear decision boundary (at p = 0.5) for a polynomial regularized logistic regression.

I can easily replicate the plot with the base library:

```
contour(u, v, z, levels = 0)
points(x = data$Test1, y = data$Test2)
```

where:

```
u <- v <- seq(-1, 1.5, length.out = 100)
```

and z is a matrix 100x100 with the values of z for every point of the grid.
Dimension of data is 118x3.

I cannot do it in ggplot2. Does somebody know how to replicate the same in ggplot2? I tried with:

```
z = as.vector(t(z))
ggplot(data, aes(x = Test1, y = Test2) + geom_contour(aes(x = u, y = 
v, z = z))
```

But I get the error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (118): colour, x, y, shape

Thanks.

EDIT (Adding plot created from code of missuse):

[image]

Comment: This new package looks like it can assist with that: https://github.com/clauswilke/isoband

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you need is to convert the coordinates into long format. Here is an example using volcano data set:

```
data(volcano)
```

in base R:

```
contour(volcano)
```

[image]

with ggplot2:

```
library(tidyverse)
as.data.frame(volcano) %>% #convert the matrix to data frame
  rownames_to_column() %>% #get row coordinates
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>% #convert to long format
  mutate(key = as.numeric(gsub("V", "", key)), #convert the column names to numbers
         rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_contour(aes(x = rowname, y = key, z = value))
```

[image]

if you would like to label it directly as in base R plot you can use library `directlabels`:

First map the color/fill to a variable:

```
as.data.frame(volcano) %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>%
  mutate(key = as.numeric(gsub("V", "", key)),
         rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_contour(aes(x = rowname,
                   y = key,
                   z = value,
                   colour = ..level..)) -> some_plot
```

and then

```
library(directlabels)

direct.label(some_plot, list("far.from.others.borders", "calc.boxes", "enlarge.box", 
                     box.color = NA, fill = "transparent", "draw.rects"))
```

[image]

to add markers at specific coordinates you just need to add another layer with appropriate data:

the previous plot

```
as.data.frame(volcano) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>% 
  mutate(key = as.numeric(gsub("V", "", key)), 
         rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_contour(aes(x = rowname, y = key, z = value)) -> plot_cont
```

add layer with points for instance:

```
plot_cont +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(x = c(35, 47, 61),
                               y = c(22, 37, 15)),
             aes(x = x, y = y), color = "red")
```

you can add any type of layer this way: `geom_line`, `geom_text` to name a few.

[image]

EDIT2: to change the scale of the axis there are several options, one is to assign appropriate `rownames` and `colnames` to the matrix:

I will assign a sequence from 0 - 2 for the x axis and 0 - 5 to the y axis:

```
rownames(volcano) <- seq(from = 0,
                         to = 2,
                         length.out = nrow(volcano)) #or some vector like u
colnames(volcano) <- seq(from = 0,
                         to = 5,
                         length.out = ncol(volcano)) #or soem vector like v

as.data.frame(volcano) %>% 
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  gather(key, value, -rowname) %>% 
  mutate(key = as.numeric(key), 
         rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_contour(aes(x = rowname, y = key, z = value))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, your solution works, it draws the expected contour. There is just a problems: the scale of the x and y axes is not from -1 to 1.5 (u and v), but goes until 100.

Comment: @Melvin86 added edits for both the deleted comment and the one addressing the scale of the `x` and `y` axes.

Comment: Thank you missuse, this works perfectly. Adding the plot to my question for reference. Ciao!

Answer (score 3):

ggplot2 works most efficiently with data in long format. Here's an example with fake data:

```
library(tidyverse)  

u <- v <- seq(-1, 1.5, length.out = 100)

# Generate fake data
z = outer(u, v, function(a, b) sin(2*a^3)*cos(5*b^2))
rownames(z) = u
colnames(z) = v

# Convert data to long format and plot
as.data.frame(z) %>% 
  rownames_to_column(var="row") %>% 
  gather(col, value, -row) %>% 
  mutate(row=as.numeric(row), 
         col=as.numeric(col)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(col, row, z=value)) +
  geom_contour(bins=20) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi eipi10, thank you for your answer, I already created the plot with missuse's code. I did not test but I think your code could work as well for my case as the codes are pretty similar.