# How to plot a contour plot from a matrix with a non equally spaced axis using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, contour

I'm a `R` beginner. I made an operation between 2 random vectors and the result was a matrix. How can I make a contour plot using as `x label` the `vector1`, as `y label` the `vector2` and z the `result` matrix?

```
library(ggplot2)

vector1 <- c(0,1,4,9,11,18)
vector2 <- c(1,5,7,9,14,16,17,20,40)

result <- matrix(0, nrow = length(vector2), ncol = length(vector1))
for (i in seq_len(length(vector2))) {
  for (j in seq_len(length(vector1))) {
    result[i,j] <- 1 + (vector2[i] * (vector1[j]))
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - ggplot2 contour plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50242331/r-ggplot2-contour-plot)

Comment: This new package looks like it can assist with this: https://github.com/clauswilke/isoband

Comment: Equivalent matrix build: `result <- sapply(vector1, function(i, j) 1 + (i * j), vector2)`.